# Magento Getting error while creating configurable products

Tags: magento

I recently created a attribute named `tshirt_color` and using that attribute i'm creating a configurable product. But while saving that configurable product i'm getting this error

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '111-0-1' for key 1`

Please share your opinion to solve this issue....

Answer (score 0):

this happens on magento v1.6

you can first try truncating tables of logs beginning with 'log_'
this [link](http://phpmysqltalk.com/1099-magento-1-6-upgrade-errors-with-solutions.html) can help as well